# Microsoft Graph API : How to share an item to specific user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The graph document already have a createLink api to create an sharing link with
`POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/createLink` with the scope 'organisation' or 'anonymous'

But i want to use the Graph API to share an item to specific user.

Anyone know how to solve this. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the invite API for that - see https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_invite

Comment: problem solved. Thank you so much. You saved my life